# Remove elements from a list according to indexes list efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have two very large lists of ints: `list1` and `list2`.

In `list1` I have indexes of `list2` (some are invalid),  I need to remove the elements in these indexes from `list2`.

This is my code:

```
for index in list1:
    if index >= 0 and index < len(list2):  # verify index is valid
        list2.pop(index)
```

This is working, but I'm would like to have a faster solution than this. Is it possible? Maybe using `numpy`?

Comment: You should be careful deleting list elements in place. I can lead to many problems.

Comment: If you can sacrifice memory for speed, you could simply create a new list with a comprehension. Almost always the fastest option.

Comment: Why is it problematic @MarkyPython?

Comment: Say for instance I wish to iterate through a list and delete all elements that are less than 3 characters. If I was to delete the items while iterating through the list, then the list elements would "shift to the left" by one index every time I delete an element. So if I delete the item at index 3 during the iteration, then on the next iteration it will check the item at index 4. Since we deleted item 3 and caused a leftward "shift" of the elements, item 4 became item 3 and now when we check item 4 it is actually item 5 from the original list, so we have skipped item 4 from the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing you use *efficiently* referring to time complexity. Let's name `n` and `m` as the sizes of `list1` and `list2`.

Your solution seems to be the best option but it's not given Python [`.pop()` operates in O(m)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) so it takes O(n*m).

With no more information, list comprehension solutions are a bad idea in general as you should test if index is inside `list1` which is O(n). So the solution:

```
filtered = [item for index, item in enumerate(list2) if index not in list1]
```

performs in O(n*m) too.

But you could make that `in` operation to be O(1) if `list1` were a set. The construction of this set is O(n) if you do:

```
ignore_indices = { index for index in list1 if 0 < index < len(list2) }
```

Now you can construct another filtered list ignoring positions in this set:

```
filtered = [item for index, item in enumerate(list2) if index not in ignore_indices]
```

And this run O(m) so the final complexity is in O(n+m).

By the way, I think your validation check is `0 <= index < len(list2)` but I'm not sure if you're excluding 0 intentionally or not.

Comment: Thanks @Salva! And, yes i updated my question to check `index >= 0`.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: I've just noticed that this answer actually does the *inverse* of what Andy is asking, it removes the items in `list2` whose indices are *not* in `list1`. I am going to leave it here in case someone attempting to do that comes across this question, but be aware that what follows is *not* the solution to Andy's query; for that have a look at Salva's answer instead.

**Original Answer:**

Here is a solution that uses a list comprehension (and also avoids checking the length of list2 on every iteration):

```
list2_length = len(list2)

list2 = [list2[index] for index in list1 if index > 0 and index < list2_length]
```

Comment: Was just about to post something similar.