# In Python, what is the best way to remove a elements from a list by index under the condition that the no new list is created?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to remove all elements corresponding to an index from another list. For example,

> my_lst = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]

I would like to remove the elements at indexes `idxs = [1,3,9,6,4]`.

What is the preferred way to do this under the constraint that the list itself should be modified (i.e. Do not generate a new list -- so no list comprehensions)?

Essentially, what is the closest I can come to for

> del my_lst[idxs]
>
> [100,300,600,700,800,900]

The problem is that when an item is deleted, the index shifts from that point on. So solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892032/remove-elements-from-a-list-according-to-indexes-list-efficiently) will not work. I have looked through other solutions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove later indexes first so their position does not get shifted by removing smaller ones first:

```
my_lst = [0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]  # added 0 index number


# sort reversed: 9,6,4,3,1 
for i in sorted([1,3,9,6,4], reverse=True):
    del my_lst[i]

print(my_lst)
```

Output:

```
[0, 200, 500, 700, 800, 1000]
```

Answer (score 0):

my_lst = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]

idxs = [1,3,9,6,4]

```
for i in range(0,len(idxs)):
    my_lst[idxs[i]]='d'

my_lst = [x for x in my_lst if x != 'd']
```